# How to make an inputbox data as Vlookup or Xlookup lookupValue?

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me on this error;

```
Dim AlloySpec As String
    AlloySpec = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Alloy Spec. Eg: 304 or 2205", Title:="ENTER DATA", Type:=2)
 

    Dim AlloyR As Range
    Set AlloyR = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Range of Alloy", Title:="SELECT RANGE", Type:=8)

    AlloyR.Value = "=XLOOKUP(AlloySpec,R8C1:R15C1,R8C2:R15C2,""not found"",0,1)"
```

** The error is when this vba can't return **AlloySpec** as value in Xlookup Lookup Value.
If I directly enter the lookup value in the formula, I will give an expecting result in excel. But if I refer AlloySpec as InputBox it will show **=XLOOKUP(@AlloySpec,$A$8:$A$15,$B$8:$B$15,"not found",0,1)**

[image]

[image]

My expecting result is as the screen shot. When I enter 2205 in the input box the Xlookup lookup value will be detected.

Thanxxxx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code. It doesn't matter if I enter a number or a text. The setup of the `AlloyR.Value` formula is wrong. If you want to use the variable `AlloySpec` as the lookup value, you must reference the variable properly.

Like this:

```
AlloyR.Value = "=XLOOKUP(" & AlloySpec & ",R8C1:R15C1,R8C2:R15C2,""not found"",0,1)"
```

[image]

Comment: teylyn, thanks to your comment!

Comment: teylyn, thanks to your comment!   After I added " & to the opening and closing **AlloySpec** word, the vba working in my file. For your case, I think It wasn't work due to you doesn't have the table (maybe). Afterall, thanks a lot. You save my day!